# How can I get gulp-typescript to output to the same directory as the source file?

Tags: typescript, gulp

I have the following pipeline

```js
  function typescripts() {
    return gulp.src(paths.watchedFiles.ts)
        .pipe(cached('typescripts'))
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(addsrc(paths.ts.include))
      //TODO: Need to eliminate the original source path (ex. /users/userName) from the sourcemap file.
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsProjectMode, undefined, ts.reporter.fullReporter(true))).js
        .pipe(gulpIgnore.exclude(paths.ts.excludeFromPostCompilePipeline))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate({
          remove: false,
          add: true,
          gulpWarnings: false //typescript removes base path for some reason.  Warnings result that we don't want to see.
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {includeContent: false}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.ts.basePath));
  }
```

I seem to have to make "hard code" the dest path based on the root of the src path.  If my src path is `app/modules/**.ts` my dest path must be `app/modules`.  This limits me to using a single root src path and I cannot use siblings.

I would like to be able to make my src `['path1/**/*.ts', 'path2/**/*.ts]` and have the transpiled output written to the same folder where the source file was located.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have source files like that:

```
gulp.src(['path1/**/*.ts', 'path2/**/*.ts])
```

Than it's equal to that:

```
gulp.src(['./path1/**/*.ts', './path2/**/*.ts], { base: '.' })
```

Which means, you can put your destination to:

```
gulp.dest('.')
```

since that's the lowest common denominator. The rest is done by Gulp.

Comment: For me this configuration results in output files placed into the root directory. I had to add `base` option to get desired result:  `gulp.src(paths.ts, { base: "." })`

Comment: @DarkDaskin I wish I had read this comment beforehand. Now I have 100 files to clean up from my root... this solution was needed for me too. On another note, you should make this a separate answer.