# gulp-typescript with gulp-sourcemap: output files to same directory

Tags: typescript, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps, gulp-typescript

I'm using `gulp-typescript` and `gulp-sourcemaps` to compile TypeScript with sourcemaps. I want to output both the `.js` and the source map files to the same directory as the original `.ts` file.

I'm using a `tsconfig.json` file to configure TypeScript, and I'm using `typings` for managing TypeScript definition files. All of my own code is in the `js` directory. Here's my project structure:

```
project root
|-- js/
|   |-- subdir/
|   |   |-- someScript.ts
|   |-- app.ts
|-- typings/
|   |-- someDefinitionFile.d.ts
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- tsconfig.json
```

Now I would like `app.js` to appear in the `js` directory, and `someScript.js` to appear in `js/subdir`. Plus, when debugging in Chrome, I would like to keep the same folder structure in the 'Sources' tab.

I've configured the following gulp task for this:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task("ts", function () {
    var tsResult = tsProject
      .src()
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(ts(tsProject)).js
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("js"));
});
```

This effectively outputs the `.js` files in the correct directories. However, when running this in Chrome and opening Development tools, the `.ts` files are located in a 'source' directory under the root, meaning the source map files contain an incorrect root.

What should be changed to show the `.ts` files and the `.js` files in the same location?

Note: this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505055/how-can-i-get-get-gulp-typescript-to-output-to-the-same-directory-as-the-source) one, except that I want to use `tsconfig.json`, and thus cannot use `gulp.src` or its `base` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the `sourceRoot` property of the gulp-sourcemap write options. This task works:

```
gulp.task("ts", function () {
    tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsProject)).js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write({sourceRoot: "/js"}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("js"));
});
```